# Page Numbers and Margins

Tags: margins, page-numbering

I am sure this is a very simple question, but here it goes.

I am writing a document (using the `report` document class) that requires one inch margins on the top and bottom of the page. I used the `geometry` package to set the margins as follows:

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in,left=1.5in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in,
  paperheight=11.0in]{geometry}
```

I want the page numbers to also appear 1 inch from the bottom of the page (in the center). By default they appear within the margin and are less than 1 inch from the bottom of the page. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add `includefoot` to the keywords for `geometry`:

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=11.0in,
  left=1.5in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in,
  includefoot,heightrounded]{geometry}
```

Adding also `heightrounded` is better, although it could slightly modify the top or bottom margin, because it ensures that an integer number of lines fits the text block.

Not that having those margins makes for a good layout, of course. But I understand that you can have some requirements to satisfy.